# Online learning of LDA model in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, lda, apache-spark-ml

Is there a way to train a LDA model in an online-learning fashion, ie. loading a previously train model, and update it with new documents ?

Comment: stackoverflow usually encourage adding some code of your own try to solve the issue. Sometimes it's more helpful than bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering myself : it is not possible as of now.

Actually, Spark has 2 implementations for LDA model training, and one is [OnlineLDAOptimizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.OnlineLDAOptimizer). This approach is especially designed to incrementally update the model with mini batches of documents.

> The Optimizer implements the Online variational Bayes LDA algorithm, which processes a subset of the corpus on each iteration, and updates the term-topic distribution adaptively.
>
> Original Online LDA paper: [Hoffman, Blei and Bach, "Online Learning for Latent Dirichlet Allocation." NIPS, 2010](https://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/info6150/readings/HoffmanBleiBach2010b.pdf).

Unfortunately, the current mllib API does not allow to load a previously trained LDA model, and add a batch to it.

Some mllib models support an `initialModel` as starting point for incremental updates (see [KMeans](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans), or [GMM](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.GaussianMixture)), but LDA does not currently support that. I filled a JIRA for it : [SPARK-20082](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20082). Please upvote ;-)

For the record, there's also a JIRA for streaming LDA  [SPARK-8696](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8696)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that such a thing would exist. LDA is probabilistic parameter estimation algorithm ( a very simplified explanation of the process here [LDA explained](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-explanation-of-Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation)), and adding a document or a few would change all previously computed probabilities, so literally recompute the model.

I don't know about your use case, but you can think about doing an update by batch if your model converges in a reasonable time and discard some of the oldest document at each re-computation to make the estimation faster.